How to avoid rocking side to side after touchdown?
I'm a fresh student pilot with about 20 flight hours in an Aquila A210. One thing that sometimes seems to happen to me is that after touchdown, the plane slightly swerves to one side (I can feel it in the rudder pedals, too), which I instinctively try to compensate, but end up overcompensating and rocking the plane side to side instead - which is really not good.
I would like to know why this happens and how to avoid it, or react in case it does happen.
A theory I have is that I am already applying rudder input on short final to line the nose up with the runway, which from my understanding will also angle the nose wheel. Upon touchdown, that's where the plan will want to roll on the ground. Could this be the reason?
How do I fix it?

Is wikipedia right that your nosewheel is directly steerable, not free-castering?

@CamilleGoudeseune Correct, from my understanding it is directly steerable.

What does your CFI say?

@300D7309EF17 He says I should 'stop rocking the aircraft' or basically just 'not do it', but did not go fully into detail as to what initiates this behaviour in the first place that would help me avoid it entirely.

Have you asked him how to fix it? i.e., the same question you asked here.

@FreeMan Well yes, that was basically his reply. 'Just don't do it'.

My own airplane is like that, though it's a low wing with a wide oleo main gear and doesn't lean in turns. But it will turn to the side somewhat if a large rudder input is held through nosewheel contact.
A special technique is required when landing airplanes in crosswinds with a steerable nosewheel that has a direct, rigid linkage, as opposed to being connected via a bungee strut that provides springiness or compliance in the rudder pedal connection to the nosewheel (for example, in traditional trainer world, Cessnas use compliant connections, and Piper Cherokees are rigid).
You should be noticing that when the nose wheel contacts the runway while holding a rudder input, you feel the pedals jerk under your feet. If you are holding firm rudder pressure at the point of contact, your feet keep the wheel from fully aligning and the airplane darts to the side because the transition from rudder surface effect to wheel traction effect is immediate.
You need to relax the foot pressure on the rudder pedals about, say, half a second before you let the nosewheel make contact, so that the wheel can caster straight without impediment. Don't take your feet off, just ease off the pressure until you feel the pedals jerk straight under your feet, then resume only the pressure needed to keep tracking straight. With a bit of practice, it becomes automatic and you won't even notice yourself doing it.

That is extremely helpful, thanks so much for answering!
